# Erro : The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given

Tags: php, imagem, laravel-rotas

Eu uso laravel 5.3 e estou tendo esse problema:

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given,

quando tento utilizar uma ***rota*** que retorna uma imagem de determinado usuário do meu sistema, segue o código abaixo.

Aqui está a `action` do `controller` que retorna a imagem.

```
public function getImage($filename)
{
    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get("/avatars/".$filename);

    return new Response($file, 200);
}
```

***Rota***

```
Route::get('getImage/{filename}', 'TeatcherController@getImage')
      ->name('get.image')
      ->middleware('auth');
```

Utilizando a rota para obter a imagem

> `<img src="{{ url(route('get.image', ['filename' => $user->teatchers->photoName] )) }}" alt="{{$user->teatchers->photoName }}">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Problema:*** *Faltou importar o* `namespace` *da* *classe* `Response`:

> `use Illuminate\Http\Response;`

ou, então pode ser utilizado assim:

```
public function getImage($filename)
{
    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get("/avatars/".$filename);

    return new \Illuminate\Http\Response($file, 200);
}
```

tem um ajuste que é passar junto a essa resposta o tipo da imagem, no código abaixo foi explicado como seria o código ideal.

---

***Código ideal:***

*Tem uma maneira bem mais simples que é utilizar a função* `response`:

```
public function getImage($filename)
{
    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get("/avatars/".$filename);
    $mimeType = (string)\Storage::disk('local')->mimeType("/avatars/".$filename);
    return response($file, 200, ['content-type' => $mimeType]);
}
```

<sub>**Importante:** passe o `content-type` com o ***tipo da imagem*** que está gravado no disco é um fator importante nesse tipo de carregamento de imagem, veja no exemplo de código que já foi introduzido automaticamente o `content-type` e esse função não precisa se preocupar com o `namespace`</sub>

***Referencias:***

- [Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem)
- [API Filesystem](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html)